# How to run a shell script?

Tags: objective-c, shell

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd $1
```

$1 is the path that I want to pass from the main.m which will call the script.

The script is located in the same directory as main.m.

How can I call a local script within the project?

Is it possible to compile the script into a binary so that when I execute the binary, it will also call the script?

Thanks

Comment: using `chmod 755 script.sh` you are making it executable and can  either place it in you PATH or run `./script.sh' to run it. Note that a script cannot change the environment of the parent meaning that it will change the directory but when the script exits nothing has changed for the parent shell.

Comment: What is main.m written in ?

Comment: It's written in objective-c

Comment: Are you making an iOS app, MacOS app, or command line tool? From what it sounds like, you want to create a program of some sort which is a compiled binary and run the shell command. The answer becomes "it depends" (hence the q's). You local script is pretty simplistic. You may want to actually state what you are trying to do since depending on the scenario. Helps in getting you to a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to run an embedded script file in macOS app or command line tool mode, you need wrap the script file with [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask) to implement it.

```c
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = @"/bin/bash";
task.arguments = @[@"/path/to/your_script_file"];
[task launch];

// Specify the stdout and stderr to pipe if necessary.
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
[task setStandardError:pipe];
```

Note that `NSTask` is available in macOS only.